# How to close a popup in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I need to query a third-party site with ajax. To do so I need cookies, which I retrieve by loading the site's page in a hidden frame. However, I just saw that IE (at least 11) blocks cookies set in frames if the site doesn't provide a P3P policy.

To work around that, I initially thought opening the site in a popup then closing it. But it seems impossible, as the return value of a window.open is *null* if the url is not from the same domain.

Here's some test code:

```
var foo = window.open(url);
setTimeout(function(){
    foo.close(); // fails in IE as foo is null if url is 3rd-party
}, 2000);
```

I've seen restrictions, such as Window.close can only close windows created with js (or asks confirmation), but I haven't seen anything regarding cross-domain such as my case. BTW, there's no issue with FF and Chrome. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Because of the same origin policy, you can not touch the window.

Comment: Even if its's my code that opened it in the first place? Also, Firefox and Chrome would have no problem with that?

Comment: Yes, even if your code opened it. Does not matter.

Comment: How do you explain this fiddle works in IE then: http://jsfiddle.net/sf5q3ece/ ? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it. It has nothing to do with same origin policy. The catch is I was testing the above code in a page accessed through a *http://localhost/* url. If I access the same page with *http://127.0.0.1/* instead, the `foo` variable is not null and the popup can be closed.

If anyone has any idea why some restrictions in IE apply on localhost and not on 127.0.0.1, you're welcome.